# Are Korra and Asami a couple?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

In the finale of `The Legend of Korra`, Korra and Asami step into the spirit portal holding hands and looking deeply into each others eyes. It almost felt like they are going to kiss right before it cut away. Are they supposed to be a couple now? Nowhere in the show before this point were we hinted that Korra and Asami had any kind of romantic interest toward each other.

[image: Korra and Asami]

Comment: Also, the hints were subtle, but there WERE hints that they were attracted to each other.  Korra blushes when Asami calls her pretty in Book 4, Asami is the only one Korra writes to during her recovery, etc.  They could have meant nothing, but given the ending, it's not actually accurate to say it came out of nowhere.  They'd been hinting at it since at least early Book 3.

Comment: @Nerrolken +1, This is exactly what I was getting at in my answer. In Bryan's tumblr post he affirms that there were hints, but people may not have realized it because they weren't considering a same-sex relationship to be within the realm of possibility. The hints were there, but were brushed off by many as friendship. I definitely picked up on them as I watched the series.

Comment: @Whelt Yeah, I picked up on them too, but I never dreamed they'd actually go there.  :P  I also liked the little nod in the finale, where Bolin says at Varrick's wedding that "even the longest of long shots have a chance at happiness together."  There's no way that that wasn't a hint at what was about to happen.

Comment: I would like to point out that there is more than enough evidence in the show that they are ready to start a relationship:  deep friendship, and some hints (already mentioned) at sexual attraction.  A lot of people feel surprised when they see the finale since they are interpreting it as meaning that they have been in a relationship for some time already, but it is much more natural to view it as the beginning of a relationship.

Comment: (This question was later also asked on Anime.SE: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24013/)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### **Yes. Absolutely they are a couple.**

According to the [show's writer](http://mikedimartinostory.com/2014/12/22/korrasami-confirmed/) Mike DiMartino;

> Our intention with the last scene was to make it as clear as possible
>   that **yes, Korra and Asami have romantic feelings for each other.**

And backed up by the [show's co-creator](http://bryankonietzko.tumblr.com/post/105916338157/korrasami-is-canon-you-can-celebrate-it-embrace) Bryan Konietzko

> **Korrasami is canon.**
>
> You can celebrate it, embrace it, accept it, get over it, or whatever
>   you feel the need to do, but there is no denying it. That is the
>   official story. We received some wonderful press in the wake of the
>   series finale at the end of last week, and **just about every piece I
>   read got it right: Korra and Asami fell in love. Were they friends?
>   Yes, and they still are, but they also grew to have romantic feelings
>   for each other.**

Comment: Hmmm. If your goal is to make something "as clear as possible", saying it outright, or even not cutting away before the kiss might achieve that goal more effectively.

Comment: @Paul - As clear as possible *within the confines of a children's TV show*

Answer (score 9):

Yes. [From the co-creator/writer himself](http://bryankonietzko.tumblr.com/post/105916338157/korrasami-is-canon-you-can-celebrate-it-embrace).

You say there were no hints, but I say go back and look at some of the Book 4 episodes again. You may notice it now that you're looking for it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes:

[image: Korra + Asami kissing]

The comic *The Legend of Korra: Turf Wars (2017) #1* (where I got these images) is pretty telling. On their Spirit World vacation they kiss. Asami says that she realized how much Korra meant to her during the [three years Korra was gone](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Korra_Alone). Korra says that she realized her feelings after she was poisoned when Asami was there for her.

Plus, this is what they tell Korra's parents when they got back:

[image: They both say "we're together"]

Comment: Great answer, Yanni

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are definitely a couple. The question of whether or not the relationship was properly foreshadowed is what gets most people exercised. I would say that this criticism must take into account more than narrative issues; it must also consider the practical reality that the writers believed Nickelodeon would only let them go so far in depicting a same-sex romance. In the end, the writers tested their assumption and found it was only partly true. Thus, Nickelodeon allowed them to hint that Korra and Asami had developed romantic feelings for each other while not allowing them to show the two women kissing. Presumably, this concern with what the network would accept affected the more traditional romantic arc that would have been done in the show if there were not issues around showing a same-sex romance. As it is, the series ends with Korra and Asami getting ready to explore feelings that each has developed for the other on their own. In other words, they are not a couple when they enter the Spirit World; they are when they leave because, in the course of their time there, they have discussed and admitted that they do have romantic feelings for each other.

Comment: This seems more like a commentary on the writing process than an actual answer to the question asked.

Answer (score -2):

I would have to say no, they are not a couple. They were not a couple at any point in the show, and every incident that hints towards them being more than friends at any point in the show needs far more justification to say they're romantically tied rather then being just friends.

I don't say this because I don't like the idea of them being a couple. I actually really like the idea of them being together. I say this because the "hints" and "evidence" is inadequate to prove they were more than just friends. Every other couple or crush on the show is talked about and stated in very clear terms. Think about how every other character talks and reacts around people they like. Clear, obvious, no subtlety. With Korra and Assami, you need to pick apart scenes and do some mental gymnastics to "prove" it.

I feel like the creators saying they were (or became a couple after the show ended) is a cop-out. They claimed to have an LGBT couple, yet did nothing within the show to... show, it.

So I say again, they are not a couple, and anything someone could say to show otherwise could just as easily be due to the close bond they shared after being kidnapped together.

Comment: But the creators said they were a couple, yes? While I can and will criticize the show's writers for being unwilling to show a same-sex relationship (if that is what was going on), they have apparently confirmed it, and were dropping hints within the show. I mean, Dumbledore's still gay, even though he did not have a relationship with anyone on-page. And I'm not totally sure that is what was going on, since Mike DiMartino said the last scene was intended to make it "as clear as possible" that Korra and Asami had a romantic connection (as indicated in the top answer).

Comment: Stephen King can say Andy Dufresne got arrested or murdered the moment after Shawshank Redemption ends, but that doesn't mean it happened.
My issue is they seem to want the recognition without the risk.
That, and from a storytelling point of view, there's nothing within the show except that very last scene of Korra and Asami holding hands as they go into the spirit world to suggest they're anything more than friends.

Comment: Some readers would say it does. ;) But in this case, the writers' statement does not contradict the show at all. While I might wish for more explicit representation, the show is entirely consistent with the idea of a budding romance between Korra and Asami. (Keep in mind, they are not a couple throughout the series: they start falling in love toward the end).